# Laravel Set boolean to only one master entry

Tags: laravel, synchronization

I'm searching for a solution of boolean entry. Let`s say I have a table "users" one of this users should be Master. colum master says 1 on master user. How can I handle changes of this? So if other master will be selected all other entries should change to 0.
Is there a solution in Laravel Like sync on Relationship table?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

idk but you can

```
User::update('master', 0);
$user->master = 1; $user->save();
```

or

```
User::update('master', 0); 
User::where('id', $id)->update('master', 1);
```